# Hibernate Transaction Query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a query for Hibernate Transaction.

In my application I have list of data which should be inserted as a whole or none. And as per business logic I need to remove all the data from that table and add insert complete list. List contains more than 100k records. Following is my code for transaction in same. It is wrong as it didn't rollback in case of one query exception for Too Long data. Can you please let me know what is wrong part in it?

```
public boolean deleteAndSaveAll(ArrayList<MyData> listBean) throws Exception {

    boolean transactionCompleted = false;

    Session session = HibernateUtils.currentSession();

    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    try {
        String stringQuery = "DELETE FROM MyData";
        Query query = session.createQuery(stringQuery);
        query.executeUpdate();

        for (MyData MyData : listBean) {
        session.save(MyData);
        }

        tx.commit();
        transactionCompleted = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        MyUtils.log("DAO: MyDataDAO error while deleteAndSaveAll : "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        if(tx != null){
        tx.rollback();
        }
        throw e;
    }finally{
        HibernateUtils.closeSession();
    }

    return transactionCompleted;
}
```

Comment: you should make checkpoints and rollback to last save checkpoint

Comment: But almost every places examples of hibernate gave this kind of example. Not sure why it didn't work. Still thanks for your suggestion. I will search it out for same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't found the proper solution for this issue.

So I need to make a work around using stored procedure.

Logic behind the seen in Stored procedure is like below.

- Pass complete information that I want to insert to stored procedure
- Stored procedure does all the back end process like validating and arranging the data.
- Insert all that data to another temporary table where table schema is same as our table.
- truncate existing table and copy all the data from temporary table to actual table.

Above procedure is much much more faster than the ritual process of insert.